# concat inside Laravel helper in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make this code:

```php
<a href="{{ route('my.route') }}" />
```

The var `$actividades["route"]` returns `my.route`

How can use `$actividades["route"]` inside the `route()` helper?

I tried things like:

```php
<a href="{{ route('.$actividades["route"].') }}" />
```

but that concat is wrong made. Any help?

Comment: I tried all the answers before creating this question on SO. Maybe the route var in my db is not as should be. I will post later with screenshots my problem. Now I'm just using URL and works ok, but I want to use routes.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain to you why this is not working:

```php
<a href="{{ route('.$actividades["route"].') }}" />
```

Lets remove the blade curly braces and whats between them.

```php
<a href="" />
```

That is a valid but useless route, right? now lets check whats between the braces.

```php
{{ route('.$actividades["route"].') }}
```

You are literally, passing the string **.$actividades["route"].** And by literally, i mean that is the actual value you are passing.

As expressed on other answer, you should not be trying to concatenate anything, at least not that way. `route($actividades["route"])` or `route($actividades['route'])` should work. Notice that the kind of quotes don't matter even the braces are inside a "{{ }}"... its because Laravel Blade, first resolve whats inside the braces, so calculates the route, and thats what's given.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable is php this is how:

```
  <a href="{{ route($actividades['route']) }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't really need to concatenate anything!

```
<a href="{{ route($actividades['route']) }}">Your Link</a>
```

Tested this in a Laravel 5.6 project, passed the array $actividades to a view